# Generate Data Access Layer with t4 template

Tags: c#, .net, t4, data-access-layer

I am looking for some help or pointers explaining a bit more on generating the whole Data Access Layer with a T4 Template. For example all the INSERT etc. statements and C# methods implementing it.

Comment: Why you are Generating Data Access Layer. @Marco Munnik

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use EF? Then you don't need this, or the repository pattern because EF is already implementing repository pattern/unit of work.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do that, try the Generic Repository pattern instead, you will end up with a single interface with a single implementation using Generics which can be used for any type in your model.

```
public interface IRepository<T, K> where T : class
    {
        T Add(T item);
        bool Update(T item);
        bool DeleteById(K id);
    }
```

Implementation

```
 public class EFRepository<T, K> : IRepository<T, K>, IDisposable where T : class
    {
        protected readonly DbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly DbSet<T> _entitySet;

        public EFRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            _dbContext = context;
            _entitySet = _dbContext.Set<T>();
        }

        public T Add(T item)
        {
            item = _entitySet.Add(item);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return item;
        }

        public bool Update(T item)
        {
            _entitySet.Attach(item);
            _dbContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }

        public bool DeleteById(K id)
        {
            var item = _entitySet.Find(id);
            _entitySet.Remove(item);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Wrapping EF with a "repository" structure like this is useless. The functionality is already provided by `DbSet` and `DbContext`.

Comment: @Haitham Shaddad I will use the same words: "you should not do that'. http://rob.conery.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/

Comment: @Stijn The functionality exist in DbSet but you can't use it directly in your domain service or UI layer, also if you want to remove EntityFramework and use another data access layer, then it will not be possible without major refactorying